# VBA freezing while traversing recordset pulled from Redshift database

Tags: vba, amazon-redshift

I have this VBA code to pull a relatively small number of records (about 200) from a Redshift database.

```
Dim cnDB As New ADODB.Connection
Dim RS As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim sqlContent As String

RS.ActiveConnection = cnDB
'RS.CursorLocation = adUseClient 'tried this, but results in recordcount "<data provider or other service returned an E_FAIL status>"
RS.Open sqlContent

x = 0
 For Each fld In RS.Fields
      With ws
        x = x + 1
        .Cells(1, x).Value = fld.Name
        colIndex.Add x, fld.Name
      End With
 Next fld

If Not RS.EOF Then
    RS.MoveFirst
Else
    Debug.Print "No Results Returned."
    Exit Sub
End If

'Populates row data
rN = 1
While Not RS.EOF
    rN = rN + 1
    With ws
        For Each fld In RS.Fields  'problem is occurring somewhere in here while processing 2nd record
            With .Cells(rN, colIndex(fld.Name))
                .Value = fld.Value
            End With
        Next fld
    End With
    RS.MoveNext
Wend
```

This code had no trouble before we moved from a Vertica database. Based on some information I found while researching the problem, it seems like I might be running into trouble somehow because cursors work differently in Redshift, but if that's the issue I don't know how to fix it.

I tried "Use Declare/Fetch" instead of "Retrieve Entire Result Into Memory" in the DSN connection options, but I'm really just grasping at straws now. It didn't make a difference that I could see.

I ran the query directly against the Redshift db and it's working fine, returning all expected records. So the problem isn't there.

After the query runs in VBA, I'm seeing a recordset count of -1, but there are definitely records coming in. When I watch the recordset while looping through the fields, everything looks alright until a few fields into the second recordset, then I get the circle cursor and can't do anything else, indefinitely. I have to kill Excel and start over.

Thanks in advance for any pointers you might be able to give me.

Comment: What happens if you remove the bottom nested loop and call [CopyFromRecordset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-copyfromrecordset-method-excel): `ws.Cell(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset RS`?

Comment: The entire first row of data populates (31 fields), but only the first 2 fields of each of the remaining 200+ records.

Comment: It seems possible that the CopyFromRecordset would work, and the remaining 29 fields of each of the other records are just missing somehow from the recordset. Unfortunately I can't see all the recordset's data in a Watch.

Comment: This can happen with precision. What are the data types of those 31 fields? Numeric with high or max decimal digits?

Comment: There are some floats and timestamps in there. Do you think casting them as something else might help?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [Parfait](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1422451/parfait) for your help! The solution *(I thought - it's since started failing again - see comment below)* was to first replace the entire segment

```
'Populates row data
rN = 1
While Not RS.EOF
    rN = rN + 1
    With ws
        For Each fld In RS.Fields  'problem is occurring somewhere in here while processing 2nd record
            With .Cells(rN, colIndex(fld.Name))
                .Value = fld.Value
            End With
        Next fld
    End With
    RS.MoveNext
Wend
```

with

```
ws.Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset RS
```

, then I cast the floats in my query to decimals, and the timestamps to dates (not sure if both castings were necessary, but I'm not going to tinker with it now that it's working).

```
CAST(fieldThatWasFloat as DECIMAL(6,5)),
CAST(fieldThatWasTimestamp as DATE)
```

Note that some detail is lost from the timestamp, but it wasn't important here. Pretty sure it can be regained with a little trickery on the date format.

Comment: This actually has started breaking again. I am back to trying to loop through the fields, but as soon as an empty field in the 2nd record is encountered, the execution seems to freeze. The weird thing is that empty fields are handled fine within the 1st record. Hits the 2nd record, finds a few populated fields, processes fine, hits first empty field, ever-turning circle.